Distributional equality between SDEs
Let $B(t)$ be a Wiener process. We know that $X^{(1)}(t) = B(t)$ and $X^{(2)}(t) = -B(t)$ both weak solutions to the SDE
\begin{equation}
dX(t) = dB(t), \quad X(0) = 0.
\end{equation}
Now let $B(t)$ and $W(t)$ be independent Wiener processes, and let $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ be two Ito processes satisfying the SDEs
\begin{equation}
d X(t) = dB(t) + dW(t) \quad \text{and}\quad d Y(t) = dB(t) - dW(t). 
\end{equation}
The solution of both SDEs is
\begin{equation}
X(t) = X(0) + B(t) + W(t) \quad \text{and} \quad Y(t) = Y(0) + B(t) - W(t)
\end{equation}
My understanding is that if $X(0) = Y(0)$, the distribution of these two processes is the same, and then that would mean that I could have written the SDE for $X(t)$ as $d X(t) = dB(t) - dW(t)$ and nothing would change.
Ultimately this leads me to believe that the SDEs
\begin{equation}
dX(t) = X(t) dt + X(t) dB(t), \quad \text{and} \quad dX(t) = X(t) dt -X(t) dB(t)
\end{equation}
describe the same process. Or are they the same in a weak sense, but not in a strong sense?

What you write about the weak solutions $X^1=B$ and $X^2=-B$ of $dX=dB$ is correct. But I firmly believe that from the introduction of "the" Wiener processes $B$ and $W$ onwards you are getting onto slippery ice because it is unclear if your solutions are weak or strong.

Thanks! The solutions should be weak for this to hold.

The SDEs
\begin{equation}
dX(t) = X(t) dt + X(t) dB(t), \quad \text{and} \quad dY(t) = Y(t) dt -Y(t) dB(t)
\end{equation}
have the following strong solutions Solution to General Linear SDE
$$X(t)=X_0 exp(\frac{t}{2}+B_{t})\text{ and }Y(t)=Y_0 exp(\frac{t}{2}-B_{t}).$$
So they are only equal only up to distribution, not almost surely.
